# Cron script Prestashop (php)

Tags: php, prestashop, cron, prestashop-1.6

I need to make a **cron script** ('cron_script.php') that updates a XML. The static functions that make this are defined in my main module class 'xmlmodule.php'.

My problem is the **cron script doesn't run module class with 'require' or  'require_once'**. The prestashop configuration values are not loaded in script so is always exiting. If I comment the 'if' statement for check '_PS_VERSION_' I have an error output because is not finding the 'Module' class.

Here is my module main class ('xmlmodule.php'):

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class XmlModule extends Module {
    //Module functions
}
```

And this is my cron script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "Before require once </br>";
require_once('xmlmodule.php'); //This exits the script
echo "<h2>Prueba CRON updateFeed</h2>"; //Never executed
```

I'm executing it locally with **curl and crontab** and my PrestaShop version is 1.6 with **PHP7.0**. I know about modules use cron scripts but I can find anything of code for see how to do it.

Does anyone know? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try including these prestashop files inside your xmlmodule.php

```
$site_base_path="./";
require_once($site_base_path . 'config/config.inc.php'); 
require_once($site_base_path . 'init.php');
```

This way, your script will have access to all the neede prestashop classes , constants etc.

Comment: Sounds great! I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

in PrestaShop cron always add at the beginning:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
```

If the cron is module is fine as I wrote it, or increase or decrease the "../" directory.

With that include the function of PrestaShop global functions and variables

Comment: Yap, I know it know haha. It's extrange cause classes executed in prestashop doesn't need the config include. Always learning! Thanks a lot!